# Weird Behaviour in Python Multiple Inheritance when Calling Superclass Methods

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

Please, can someone explain why this code does this:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("A")

class B:
    def foo(self):
        print("B")

class C(A, B):
    def foo(self):
        super(A, self).foo()
        super(B, self).foo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = C()
    c.foo()
```

and how I can get it to do the desired behaviour (printing `"A"` then `"B"` when I call `c.foo()`?
P.S. Similar questions have been asked before but no one has provided a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class C(A, B):
    def foo(self):
        A.foo(self)
        B.foo(self)
```

this code gets around the issues but does not respect the inheritance hierarchy